# How to interpret RMSEA = 0 and RMSR = 0 in exploratory factor analysis?

Tags: factor-analysis

My dataset consists of 120 observations, and 7 observed variables. I'm using 3 factors (result from parallel analysis and theory). All 7 variables load relatively well (2 in factor 1, 2 in factor 2, 3 in factor 3). The Tucker Lewis Index =  1.034 and CFI = 1.004, which looks OK. However, I'm getting RMSEA and RMSR values of zero and I'm not sure what to make of this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this exploratory or confirmatory factor analysis?

Comment: Hi Jeremy, it's exploratory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you have very good fit. Any time that chi-square is less than df, then RMSEA will be zero.

But the value of RMSR is a bit troubling. Is it exactly zero?  I would be a little suspicious, and check this out further. Can you get the predicted correlation matrix, and compare it to what you have?

CFI is also troubling. CFI cannot go above 1.00 (normally). (TLI can - that's OK.)

Comment: Yes, the RMSR is exactly zero. I calculated the CFI manually, as the "psych" package in R doesn't provide it. CFI = 1 - ((chi square - degrees of freedom) / (chi square - null degrees of freedom)) Do you know if there's another R package that I can use to compare the results?

Comment: The df corrected root mean square of the residuals is  0.01, if that helps

Comment: Check your CFI formula, e.g. here: http://davidakenny.net/cm/fit.htm